# Problem with azure-cognitiveservices-speech on heroku

Tags: python, azure, heroku

I would like deploy my app to heroku server.
When I send request i response this log:

> 2020-05-26T13:30:56.122694+00:00 app[web.1]:     _speech_py_impl = swig_import_helper()
>   2020-05-26T13:30:56.122695+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/speech_py_impl.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
>   2020-05-26T13:30:56.122695+00:00 app[web.1]:     return importlib.import_module('_speech_py_impl')
>   2020-05-26T13:30:56.122696+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
>   2020-05-26T13:30:56.122696+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   2020-05-26T13:30:56.122702+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_speech_py_impl'

I have problem with install **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_speech_py_impl'**

My file requirement.txt

```
Flask
requests
gunicorn
azure-cognitiveservices-speech
```

Also I have a problem run this command on heroku:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl1.0.0 libasound2
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I got this problem too.
Here's how I fix it.

1. Add this [buildpack](https://github.com/hopkinschris/heroku-buildpack-apt) to your heroku app.

> https://github.com/hopkinschris/heroku-buildpack-apt

2. Create a file call **Aptfile** in your project.
3. Put the name of package you want to install in **Aptfile** just like the **requirement.txt**

```
build-essential
libssl1.0.0
libasound2
```